# WHERE clause null? don't understand

Tags: mysql

The query below is correct.  It returns the rows `paul` and `rick` because they have the highest rating of the child rows.  This was solved for me with the below link.  I am having trouble understanding the query.  I understand joins, what i don't understand is `t2.rating is null`?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e60/2

```
select t1.* from mytable t1
    left join mytable t2
    on t1.parentid = t2.parentid and t1.rating < t2.rating
    join mytable parents
    on parents.id = t1.parentid
    where t2.rating is null AND parents.name like '%mike%'
```

`t1.rating < t2.rating` gets the highest rated values for the child rows, i know `t2.rating is null` means t2.rating is false but i have no idea what it is doing in the query?  I removed it and other results were added.  So what does it do exactly to eliminate the incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

Because you've got a `left join` (rather than a `join`) you'll get rows from `t1` even if there aren't any matching rows from `t2`. Specifying `t2.rating is null` just means you'll only get rows form `t2` where the rating is null.

Any comparison to `null` is false, even when both sides are `null`. The combination of `t2.rating is null` in the where clause and `t1.rating < t2.rating` in the join clause means you'll *never* get any rows from `t2`, because those conditions can never both be `true`.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help...so t2.rating is null eliminates rows from t2 and t1.rating <t2.rating attaches the highest child rows to the LEFT table?

Comment: This seems inconsistent with OP's claim: _"The query below is correct. It returns the rows `paul` and `rick`..."_.

Comment: This answer is wrong. the WHERE clause applies after the LEFT JOIN is applied. I think that in the original table there a 0 lines with rating = NULL. the WHERE clause only keep the lines on the left for which the ON clause can never be matched

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation:

1/ when you do a LEFT JOIN, for each row in the left table (t1), you get at least one result.

2/ If, via the ON clause, the t1 row cannot match any of the t2 rows, you get a NULL t2 row (same columns as t2, but filled with NULL values).

3/ So, the WHERE t2.rating IS NULL actually filters the table t1, and only keeps those rows for which the ON clause can never be matched

4/ Reading the ON clause, these filtered rows are the rows for which no other row has a higher rating : if the t1 row was not the highest rating, there would be a line in t2 with a higher rating ; this line would match the ON clause, and t2.rating would not be NULL !

5/ So the filtered lines correcly match what you are looking for : the highest rating rows

I hope this will clarify things for you !

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare nulls with anything other than "is null" or "is not null".  I think [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) best describes it.